# Getting 502 Bad Gateway when I use HtmlUnit requests multiple times in the same execution

Tags: java, http, htmlunit

I need to send an automatic request to a webpage once every 30 minutes, I used htmlUnit and worked at first, but from the third attempt to send the request I start getting 502 Bad Gateway error. When I try to use a web browser the website works perfectly.

I tried waiting for a few minutes then trying again when I get the error but I just keep getting the same error for every subsequent request.

once every 30 minutes, I'm looping over the following code:

```
        page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.website.com");
        response = page1.getWebResponse();
        HtmlCheckBoxInput input = page1.getHtmlElementById("checkbox");
        input.setChecked(true);
        HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("form");

        HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("button");
        page2 = button.click();
        response = page2.getWebResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the browser get a cookie or some session information that is required to issue subsequent calls.

Use developer tools to get the actual http trace for the website usage and try to mimic that.